# How to define a matrix with a data type of a class in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a class Neuron in python, i need do define a matrix with the dimensions i j , that are given to me, which individual ij positions is a neuron.

```
Mneurons = np.arange(matrizi*matrizj).reshape(matrizi,matrizj)
```

But this creates with datatype = int, i need to create with datatype = Neuron

```
class Neuron:
def __init__(self,name):...
```

Thanks !